# Is there a way to selectively remove an Emacs shell buffer's shell history entries?

Tags: shell-mode, history

I know how to view a shell buffer's<sup>1</sup> shell history, but is there a way to remove entries from this history, so that these entries will no longer be accessible by commands like `comint-previous-input`?

If there is a choice on the matter, I have a slight preference for solutions using Emacs Lisp, but interactive solutions are fine too.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> By this I mean a buffer that was initiated by running `M-x shell`.</sup>

Comment: Are you asking how to do this interactively or using Emacs Lisp? Please update the question to state more clearly what you're requesting. Thx.

Comment: The history is stored in a buffer-local variable called `comint-input-ring`. You can find more information about rings in the [Emacs Lisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rings.html). In particular, you can remove elements *if you know the index of the element you want to remove* by using `ring-remove`. That's almost certainly the underpinnings of any solution, but without some superstructure, manipulating the history is going to be painful.